# Concurrent request fail - "Session is closed!"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, concurrency

I dono what is wrong with my below code. If I hit my request from browser, it works fine. But when I give concurrent requests, it fails saying **Session is closed!**. I am hitting the below two urls simultaneously or concurrently (async calls).

```
http://localhost:8080/getEmployee
http://localhost:8080/getDepartment
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getEmployees", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody List<Employee> getEmployee() {

        List<Employee> empList = null;
        empList = services.getEmployee();
        return empList;
    }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/getDepartments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody List<Department> getDepartment() {

        List<Department> deptList = null;
        deptList = services.getDepartment();
        return deptList;
    }
```

Two Model class

```
Table 1 (Employee)
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2650114334774359089L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

// getter setter
```

//Second model class

```
Table 2 (Department)
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2650114334774359089L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "dept_name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String dept_name;

    // getter setter
```

DAOImpl

```
@Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DataDaoImpl.class);
    public List<Employee> getEmployee() throws Exception {
        List<Employee> result = null;
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        String hql = "from Employee";
        Query lQuery = session.createQuery(hql);
        result = lQuery.list();
        tx = session.getTransaction();
        session.beginTransaction();
        tx.commit();
        return result;
    }

    public List<Department> getDepartment() throws Exception {
        List<Department> result = null;
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        String hql = "from Department";
        Query lQuery = session.createQuery(hql);
        result = lQuery.list();
        tx = session.getTransaction();
        session.beginTransaction();
        tx.commit();
        return result;
    }
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Override
    public List<Employee> getEmployee() throws Exception {
        return dataDao.getEmployee();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Department> getDepartment() throws Exception {
        return dataDao.getDepartment();
    }
```

spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.srdh.model.Employee</value>
                <value>com.srdh.model.Department</value>

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataDao" class="com.test.dao.DaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="dataServices" class="com.test.service.ServicesImpl"></bean>
```

Can anyone help me what I my doing wrong in my code. I have only one DAO to access both the department and employee table. I have to fetch records from the individual tables and show in output. In concurrent request it is failing.

Error Stack trace

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.srdh.dao.DataDaoImpl.getDepartment(DataDaoImpl.java:49)
    at com.srdh.service.DataServicesImpl.getDepartment(DataServicesImpl.java:26)
    at com.srdh.controller.MainController.getDepartment(MainController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.srdh.dao.DataDaoImpl.Employee(DataDaoImpl.java:126)
    at com.srdh.service.DataServicesImpl.Employee(DataServicesImpl.java:71)
    at com.srdh.controller.MainController.Employee(MainController.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: "it fails saying Session is closed!." - I bet it says more, e.g. it provides a stacktrace etc. As a general rule: whenever you ask about some exception/error provide as much information on the exception/error itself as you can (e.g. stacktraces and relevant portions of your code that are mentioned in the stacktrace).

Comment: @ThomasI have added the error I am getting in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DAOImpl` looks suspect.

Spring beans are normally singletons. There's only one instance of the Spring bean in your running program. You didn't post the complete code, but it looks like your class `DAOImpl` has member variables for the session and transaction.

If multiple threads are using the same singleton `DAOImpl` object concurrently, changing the member variables, then they will interfere with each other. A thread handling one request will see the session and transaction from another thread handling another request.

Do not put state (member variables) in singleton Spring beans. `session` and `tx` should not be, and do not need to be, member variables in class `DAOImpl`. Make them local variables in the methods `getEmployee` and `getDepartment` instead.

Even better would be to use [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) instead of implementing your own DAO object. This makes it easier and you won't have to deal with lower level details yourself directly, such as getting a session and transaction.

Answer (score 2):

The Error stack trace says `createQuery is not valid without active transaction` from which we can see that there's no active transaction in other words there's no open transaction, and this is because you create and execute the `query` before opening the transaction.

So your big mistake is that you are querying the database before opening any transaction.

You need to move:

```
tx = session.getTransaction();
session.beginTransaction();
```

Before the line where you create and execute your query.

And you are using a new `Session` in each request, you should use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` instead of `sessionFactory.openSession()`.

So you need to update your code like this:

```
 public List<Employee> getEmployee() throws Exception {
    List<Employee> result = null;
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String hql = "from Employee";
    Query lQuery = session.createQuery(hql);
    result = lQuery.list();
    tx.commit();
    return result;
}


public List<Department> getDepartment() throws Exception {
    List<Department> result = null;
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String hql = "from Department";
    Query lQuery = session.createQuery(hql);
    result = lQuery.list();
    tx.commit();
    return result;
}
```

This should fix your problem.

**Note:**

As reported and pointed out by @SergeBallesta you should not use `session` and `tx` as instance variable in your `DAO`, you better use them as local varibales in your methods like in my code above.

Comment: @user4324324 Take a look at my edit, I updated my answer accordingly with your Error stack trace.

Comment: @SergeBallesta This should be reported to the OP, I am just giving him a solution regarding his error.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I got your point. No I didn't say it was safe I just didn't focused on it in my answer in the first place, I updated the code in my answer.